# PHP function GLOB: get and modify the results

Tags: php

I'm trying to import many xml files that I do not know the name. 
I use this code:

```
foreach(glob('OLD/*.xml') as $file) {
$url=  basename($file) . ', ';
$all_urls = array($url);
foreach ($all_urls as $url) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

I have a lot of files like `agency.xml`, `annunci_324.xml`, `annunci_321.xml`, ecc...

I only need the files that begin for `annunci` and end `.xml`. I also need to delete last value's comma and put it in the last foreach. how can i do it?

Comment: `glob('OLD/annunci*.xml')`

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works!. how can i manage the result to have this: ('annunci_2', 'annunci_3', 'annunci_4') without last comma? thans

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check if name contains `annunci` with `strstr` function ([**documentation here**](http://php.net/manual/it/function.strstr.php))

```
if(strstr($file, 'annunci')
{
    //we found a file with name we are interessed in.
```

Now you can build directly your array without caring about commas

```
$all_urls = array();
foreach(glob('OLD/*.xml') as $file) 
{
   if(strstr($file, 'annunci')
   {
       $all_urls[] = array(basename($file));
   }
}
```

This way we have `all_urls` as array of all the files starting with `annunci` and you can loop in it to `simple_load` them all.